# How to "connect" PHP "network" to an .svg image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, svg

Basically, there's an `img` with `src` of an .svg image. What I'm trying to do is slowly(.2s ease) change the color of it from black to white. 
Since it's not an inline `<svg>`, I can't simply change `fill` color in CSS.

I tried changing `img src` to this image's white-colored copy, but that way I won't have the transition.

I could use the crossfading technique, but I'd like to keep it simple and without `position: absolute`.

So, I came up with a solution. I change a PHP variable's color in `hover()` function of jQuery, and then `echo` that variable like so inside the .svg image itself: `fill=<?php echo "'$color'" ?>`

Here's the code:
JavaScript/jQuery(mainjs.php):

```
<?php
    $color = "";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {


    $("#svg_img").hover(
        function() {
            <?php $color = "#221e1f"; ?>
        },
        function() {
            <?php $color = "white"; ?>
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

And HTML(if necessary):

```
<img id="svg_img" src="images/um.svg" style="height: 7vh; vertical-align: middle;" alt="Home" />
```

So how would I go about doing that? If not possible — or you know a better way — then, how would I achieve my goal without the crossfading technique?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _server-side_ code and _client-side_ code.  You can't do that.

Comment: How big is the svg? Put it inline instead of in an img tag, then you can manipulate it with JS directly

Comment: Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138309/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-an-svg-document-embedded-in-an-html-doc-with-javasc

Answer (score 1):

In the hover you have to update the fill property. You don't need that PHP code in hover.

Tip:
What you're doing here is really not a good idea. Please find out what ajax and MVC is. You cannot write PHP in a JavaScript.

Comment: That would work if I this image were an inline `<svg>`, but since it's just an `<img>`, that doesn't work. I tried. That said, you did give me right now an excellent idea. As for ajax and MVC, I may look at that later, but I have to complete something I'm working on rather soon, so I've got no time to learn new things right now.

Comment: Then create two different svg for the two colors and in the hover change the src attribute from one to the other. if (src == 'x') { src == 'y' } ...
Or place two img in the page and in the hover hide() and show() them.

Comment: Did you even read what I said? Placing 2 images IS crossfading. And changing `src` doesn't work with CSS transition. Granted, I already used that troublesome crossfading technique, so no need to try hard. At least, I learned that what I asked for is impossible.

Comment: Changing src gonna be work. I am not working with css so I cannot help here, but Im sure there's a way to do this... Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416136/image-substitution-and-transition-with-css3